# Javascript code looking up for words in a description within an excel cell

Tags: javascript

Newbie here, starting to learn some coding.
How to code something that look up to a word in a description?

For example:
Cell A1 contains: "This is the best way for learning Javascript!"
If the sentence contains: "learning", print(Yes).

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

String Method: `String.includes` may solve your need

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

In case you need to filter from an array, google `filter()`

```
const sentence = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';

const word = 'fox';

console.log(`The word "${word}" ${sentence.includes(word) ? 'is' : 'is not'} in the sentence`);
// expected output: "The word "fox" is in the sentence"
```